# Conda dependency woes

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

So I'm new to using `conda` to install Python packages.

```
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
```

I wanted to install [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/install.html#installing-geopandas) so as suggested I ran

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
```

All seemed to work fine, but on trying to import geopandas I got an error message which I traced to back `fiona`:

```
>>> import fiona
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/nfs/see-fs-02_users/matmdpd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fiona/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from fiona.collection import Collection, BytesCollection, vsi_path
  File "/nfs/see-fs-02_users/matmdpd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fiona/collection.py", line 9, in <module>
    from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
ImportError: libicui18n.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In `anaconda3\lib\` I found `libicui18n.so` and a symlink `libicui18n.so.54 -> libicui18n.so`.  This gave me the idea of create symlinks from `libicui18n.so.56` (and related libraries) which worked to the extent that I got an error message about missing version `58`.  A few more symlinks, and I have `import geopandas` working!

The wrong library files appear to be C++ unicode support, see http://site.icu-project.org/

So:

- I guess I got this working by faking which version of the unicode library it wanted to pull in.
- What would have been a better way to fix this problem?
- What's going on under the hood which lead to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conda-forge people seem to have solved this as of now with build version 3 of `geopandas=0.2.1` for `python3.6`.

Under the hood, the problem arose because one of the libraries required for fiona depend directly/indirectly on `libicu (major version 56)`, which you could have verified by typing:

```
$ ldd /path/to/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fiona/_err.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Ideally this version of libicu should have been specified as a dependency for one of the packages installed while installing geopandas.

In such a scenario, you could have upgraded libicu yourself, by typing:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge icu=56.1
```

If that didn't help, you could have built the package yourself, using the recipe available at: https://github.com/conda-forge/icu-feedstock/tree/master/recipe

I have uploaded `libicu 58.2` to my channel. You can install it by typing the command:

```
$ conda install -c nehaljwani libicu=58.2
```

Comment: Is libicu 58.2 still on your channel? I'm getting a package not found error.

Comment: @EddyTheB The 58.2 version of the package is now available in defaults, but the name icu. https://anaconda.org/anaconda/icu